# How to update Windows Defender mpsigstub.exe?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-update, windows-defender

I'm trying to put together a script which will update Windows 7 with the latest Windows Defender Antivirus definitions. Microsoft continues to provide updates on [their website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/defenderupdates), being most recently updated July 2021.

Offline definitions can be downloaded and installed offline. This will successfully update the definitions file. However, it is not updating `mpsigstub.exe`, despite the updated file being contained in the definition update `mpas-fe.exe`.

[image]

Windows Update will continue to report that the latest definitions are not yet installed but will reduce the file size to only a few hundred kilobytes. Downloading this update will correctly update only `mpsigstub.exe` as expected.

[image]

Both `mpsigstub.exe` and the definitions can be updated automatically while online by running the following command:

```
cd %ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender
MpCmdRun.exe -removedefinitions -dynamicsignatures
MpCmdRun.exe -SignatureUpdate
```

The issue I'm experiencing, as mentioned earlier, is that running the offline definitions update `mpas-fe.exe` will not update `mpas-fe.exe` and leaves the system vulnerable to [CVE-2019-1161](https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/127910).

[image]

There is [a thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6c14f9c-09a0-48a0-bc9b-6341c21bdc0e/cve20191161-microsoft-defender-elevation-of-privilege-vulnerability) on Microsoft's TechNet forum where a user says:

> I found a way to update it. If I launch manually the windows defender it will update automatically the MpSigStub.exe.

I have tried running Windows Defender, stopping/starting the service, and rebooting, but nothing I have tried will update this file.

How can I update `mpsigstub.exe` offline as desired?

Comment: I get mine via windows update, set WU to download and install at a specific time.

Comment: The question is asking how to update *offline*.